# How to use the auto-completion of jedi while keeping other functions of elpy?

Tags: python, company-mode, auto-complete-mode, elpy

Currently, I have both `elpy` and `jedi` installed. `init.el` is like:

```el
(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython)
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)
```

I know that I shouldn't turn on `elpy` and `jedi` at the same time, it really causes competition and conflict in auto-completion. However, in my try I think `jedi` yielded a better completion. But I need `elpy` to manage the `ipython` interperator, check the grammer and many other issues. Also, `(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")` could not produce the same result as `jedi` did. So my question is: is it possible to disable the auto-completion of `elpy`, while keeping its remaining functions, so that I can use `jedi` for auto-completion?

Comment: Delete the jedi config part will work fine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809061/how-to-properly-setup-jedi-with-elpy-in-emacs